# Can't access IIFE inner function from Button

Tags: javascript, iife

I'm new to IIFEs and have read the material on it.

I have a basic challenge which can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/m2994n9t/5/):

HTML:

```
<input type="button" onclick="javascript:Test()" value="Click Me" />
```

JS:

```
(function () {
    function Test() {
        alert('Yay');
    }
})();
```

Basically, my issue is that I can't access the inner function from a button. 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: *"What am I doing wrong?"* ***everything.*** javascript in an onclick attribute runs on the global scope and therefore can only access function/variables that are defined on the global scope. If you were to bind your event inside of the iife, you would be able to use the function inside the iife without issue.

Comment: Kevin B, how is this a bad question deserving of a downvote though?

Comment: Would have to wait on a response from the downvoter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The inner function is scoped to the IIFE. Of course you can't access it from the global scope.

If you want to, you'll have to set `window.Test = Test` inside the IIFE.

You should also remove `javascript:` from the inline event, as it's already running as JS.